# Excel Drag Down with formula referring to 2 columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, drag

I got a problem with the dragging down in Excel. So here I am calculating the correlation between 2 columns. 
Here's the formula that I used:

```
=CORREL([RecommendationProd.xlsx]Corelation!$A:$A,[RecommendationProd.xlsx]Corelation!A:A)
```

So when it came to the next row, the formula should be:

```
=CORREL([RecommendationProd.xlsx]Corelation!$B:$B,[RecommendationProd.xlsx]Corelation!A:A)
```

Unfortunately the formula did not switch to column B automatically, but instead just simply copy the first formula.

Is there anyway that I can drag down and only change the first column (absolute reference, `$A:$A`, `$B:$B`, etc., ...) without changing the second column?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can change the references between absolute by clicking the reference and pressing F4 to cycle through. I think you need this formula in your first column:

```
=CORREL([RecommendationProd.xlsx]Corelation!A:A,[RecommendationProd.xlsx]Corelation!$A:$A)
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the prompt reply. I agree with your solution, but the problem is that after dragging down I will need to drag to the right. So basically I am making a n*n matrix. If I do what you said, I will have a problem when I drag every row in the first column to the right. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you mean you need to refer to both columns A and B when you move to the next column?

Comment: Yes. So basically the top row as items A, B, C, D, .... And the left most column has items A, B, C, D.... I am trying to calculate the correlation between A and B, C, D... and between B and A, C, D... etc.. Does that make better sense for you? Thank you dude.

Comment: You are trying to calculate the correlation of one value, against an array of values?

Comment: Not really. So basically each item has a column of sales history by date. So I am trying to calculate the correlation between each item according to their history. But the result will be an array.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how your sheet is structured?

Comment: the data is like:

                A;        B;         C;      D;  ....

01/01/2014      10        0         10       5
01/02/2014       5        2          5       3
01/03/2014       15       7         15       1
.
.
.

And the correlation table that I am trying to calculate is like:

        A      B      C      D

A       1      0.03   1      0.35  ...

B      0.03     1    0.23    -0.54   ...

C        1     0.23    1     -0.67   ...

D      0.35    -0.54  -0.67   1   ...

.
.
.
.


I hope this will make it more clear for you. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Oh shoot I cannot post since my reputation is under 10...sry